# Why Error if open and close PHP tags between switch and first case statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement, php-parse-error

Works:

```
    <?php switch ($student[$use_grade]) {
        case "K": ?>
            <?php echo 'works'; ?>
        <?php break; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Doesn't work:

```
    <?php switch ($student[$use_grade]) { ?>
        <?php case "K": ?>
            <?php echo 'works'; ?>
        <?php break; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INLINE_HTML, expecting T_CASE or T_DEFAULT or '}'

Comment: why on earth would you want to do it this way?    there is no reason to close those tags at all as there is no HTML in there at all.  Just open the php tag, put all your code in there, and then close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments documentation of PHP:

> in the case of the switch statement, can be understood as follows; in
>   any place where you can have an echo statement (an if block, a
>   switch's case, whatever), that's where you can have the raw HTML. In
>   PHP this basically gets handled just like that -- like an echo
>   statement.
>
> In between a switch and a case, though, you can't echo anything. By
>   placing the switch and the case in two separate blocks of PHP, with a
>   raw HTML newline echo'ed in between them, PHP basically had to try to
>   find where that statement would be. And it can't be there, hence the
>   difficulty.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 2):

Inline html (everything between `?>` and `<?php`) is syntactically the same as operator, and there are no operators allowed between `switch` and first `case`.

From PHP Documentation:

> Any output (including whitespace) between a switch statement and the
>   first case will result in a syntax error.